# Using augmented matrices to find a number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

There's this system of equations

$$(8 − a)x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + ax_4 = 2$$

$$x_1 + (9 − a)x_2 + 4x_3 + ax_4 = 1$$

$$x_1 + 2x_2 + (10 − a)x_3 + ax_4 = 2$$

$$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + ax_4 = 2$$

Now I have managed to find $a$, $(a=7)$ using substitution. However if you were to use matrices to do it, how would you solve the system depending on the parameter $a$?

\begin{pmatrix}
        (8-a) & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
        1 & (9-a) & 4 & a & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & (10-a) & a & 2 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Are you asking how to find $a$ so that there are no solutions to the system? This problem doesn't make any sense to me as written.

Comment: Which condition must be satisfied?

Comment: So basically can the system of equality written above be written as a augmented matrix and be reduced down to solve the system depending on the parameter $a$?

Comment: @ArthurKingLee Yes. However there is the occasional case distinction due to certain values of $a$. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gauss or Gauss-Jordan elimination to determine the solutions:
$$
A x = b \Rightarrow [A\vert b] \to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
(8-a) & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
1 & (9-a) & 4 & a & 1 \\
1 & 2 & (10-a) & a & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 2 - 2(8-a) & 3 - 3(8-a) & a - a(8-a) & 2-2(8-a) \\
0 & (9-a)-2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & (10-a)-3 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & -14 + 2 a & -21 + 3 a & -7a + a^2 & -14 + 2a \\
0 & 7-a & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 7-a & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & -21 + 3 a + 2 & -7a + a^2 & -14 + 2a - 2 \\
0 & 7-a & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 7-a & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 2 & -7a + a^2 & -14 + 2a - 2 \\
0 & 7-a & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 7-a & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

We now have to make a case distinction 1.) $a = 7 $ or 2.) $a \ne 7 $, because this determines if we can divide a row by $(7-a)$ or not, or if there is a leading non-zero entry or not, which affects the dimension of the solution space.

**Case 1 ($a = 7$):**

$$
[A\vert b]
\to 
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & - 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\\
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\\
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 2 & 0 & 7 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Case 2 ($a \ne 7$):**

$$
[A\vert b] 
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 2 & -7a + a^2 & -14 + 2a - 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1/(7-a) & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 0 & -7a + a^2 & -14 + 2a - 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 0 & -a & -2 - 2/(7-a) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & a & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 0 & -a & -2 - 2/(7-a) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -2/(7-a) \\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 0 & 0 & a & 2 + 2/(7-a) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & 2 + 2/(7-a) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The last row implies $a \ne 0$ for a solution, otherwise there would be a condition $0 = 16/7$ which is not to fulfill by any vector $x$.

**Case 3 ($a\ne 0, a\ne 7$):**

$$
[A\vert b] \to
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1/(7-a) \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & (2/a) + 2/((7-a)a) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Result:**

Thus the system has the unique solution
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-1/(7-a) \\
0 \\
(2/a) + 2/((7-a)a)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $a \ne 0, a \ne 7$.

For $a = 0$ there is no solution.

For $a = 7$ there are infinite many solutions
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
5 -2s - 7t  \\
s \\
-1 \\
t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: From the first step to the second step, can you tell me the steps you took to get to the second matrix

Comment: A multiple of the last row is substracted from the other rows each so that the first column entry turns 0. So $r_1' = r_1 - (8-a) r_4$, $r_2' = r_2 - r_4$, $r_3' = r_3 - r_4$.

Answer (score 5):

$a=7$ is not a given, correct? Because I think I found some other solutions.

Do row reductions for the matrix. You will get a matrix that looks like this: $$\left[
        \begin{array}{cccc|c}
        1 & 2 & 3 & a & 2\\
        7-a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 7-a & 1 & 0 & -1\\
        0 & 0 & 7-a & 0 & 0\\
        \end{array}
\right]$$
Although it is not a standard row-echelon from, you can still solve the system form here.
From row 4 you can see that $(7-a)x_3=0$, so either $a=7$ or $x_3=0$
From row 2 you can see that $(7-a)x_1=0$, so either $a=7$ or $x_1=0$

So you should solve for each case:
When $a=7$, with two leading 1's in column 1 & 3, you'll have two free variables $x_2$ and $x_4$. Set $x_2=r$ and $x_4=s$ and solve for $x_1$ and $x_3$ correspondingly.

When $a\not=7$, then $x_1=x_3=0$, solve for $x_2$ and $x_4$ in terms of a.